# How to inject multiple implementations of same type with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

My class **RssStrategy** injects a **RssConsumer** class. There are multiple implementations of the **RssConsumer**; therefore, Spring Boot throws an error that multiple beans of the same type have been found.

**Exception**

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in <path>.RssStrategy required a single bean, but 11 were found:
```

How would I circumvent this issue with my current implementation?
I have seen solutions where a qualifier has been used to determine which implementation to reference, but in my case, **RssStrategy.java** doesn't know, and it's up to the service that injects the Strategy to decide.

**RssStrategy.java**

```
@Component
public class RssStrategy<T extends RssConsumer> implements FetchDataStrategy{

   private final T rssConsumer;

   public RssStrategy(T rssConsumer) {
       this.rssConsumer = rssConsumer;
   }
    
   @Override
   public void fetchData() {
      rssConsumer.consume();
   }
}
```

Different implementations of **RssConsumer.java**:

```
@Component(value = "rssConsumerA")
public class RssConsumerA extends RssConsumer {
   @Override
   public void consume() {}
}

@Component(value = "rssConsumerB")
public class RssConsumerB extends RssConsumer {
   @Override
   public void consume() {}
}
```

Injecting RssStrategy in different services but always passing a different generic type implementation:

```
@Service
public class ServiceA extends MyAbstractService {
   public ServiceA ( RssStrategy<RssConsumerA> fetchDataStrategy) {}
   
   @Override
   public void run() {fetchDataStrategy.fetchData()}
}

@Service
public class ServiceB extends MyAbstractService {
   public ServiceB ( RssStrategy<RssConsumerB> fetchDataStrategy) {}
   
   @Override
   public void run() {fetchDataStrategy.fetchData()}
}
```

**Update: I figured out a solution:**

The only alternative I found out so far is instead of injecting the rssConsumer, I provide it via setter like:

```
@Component
public class RssStrategy<T extends RssConsumer> implements FetchDataStrategy{

   private final T rssConsumer;

   public setRssConsumer(T rssConsumer) {
      this.rssConsumer = rssConsumer;
   }

   @Override
   public void fetchData() {
      rssConsumer.consume();
   }
}
```

And injecting the Consumer in the Service instead and providing it via the setter method:

```
@Service
public class ServiceA extends MyAbstractService {
      public ServiceA ( RssConsumerA, rssConsumerA, 
   RssStrategy<RssConsumerA> fetchDataStrategy) {
      fetchDataStrategy.setRssConsumer(rssConsumerA);
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {fetchDataStrategy.fetchData()}
}
```

**Update 2:**
It seems that my solution also does not work. Even though I provide the rssConsumer via setter:

```
fetchDataStrategy.setRssConsumer(rssConsumerA);
```

The actual consumer seems to be rather random. I have to investigate more but it's not the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution has a drawback! Spring components are Singleton by default, so when working in a concurrent environment (such as web application), your code breaks!

Thread 1 calls `setConsumer(consumer1)`, and just before calling the second method threa2 calls `setConsumer(consumer2)` and now thread 1's method is called on `consumer2`.

To prevent the problem change the signature of your method to `fetchData(Consumer consumer)`, now you are sure using proper consumer.

---

Another solution can be using a factory, if you can determine which consumer should be used according to `fetchData` arguments, so define a class as

```
@Component
public class ConsumerFactory implements BeanFactoryAware {
   private BeanFactory beanFactory;

   public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) {
      this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
   }

   public Consumer resolverConsumer(arguments) {
      if (condition1) {
         return beanFactory.getBean('name1', Consumer.class);
      } 
      if (condition2) {
         return beanFactory.getBean('name2', Consumer.class);
      } 
      ....
   }

}
```

now inject this factory in your strategy, and you can get proper `Consumer` in your Strategy.

---

Never forget! as Spring components are singleton by default, **you must not have conversional state in them!**

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. But instead of changing the signature to fetchData(consumer) it might make more sense in my case to remove the @Component annotation on the strategy and create a new instance of it in the Service (without injection).

Comment: @M4V3N the second solution works almost as you said, but uses Components, what if your components needed to be injected?